# How to introduce headers for socket programming in vs code (c)?

Tags: c, .net, sockets, visual-studio-code, posix

I am starting up a project for a course and I am using Windows on my PC, but the final executable is supposed to be working for debian. I am using vs code and i get the error "cannot open source file "sys/socket.h"".

I tried using a solution mentioned under another thread here (replacing "sys/socket.h" with an #ifdef WIN_32) i still got the error.

Comment: Why torture yourself coding in Windows if the release will be for Debian (or vice versa)? Windows and Linux use different, non-compatible socket libs. You can emulate Linux:ish behavior with MSYS2 but I have no idea if it supports some wrapper for Linux socket API on top of winsock.

Comment: There are no c library files in the default window environment. You can connect to your Debian through ssh in vscode if you are not familiar with linux environment, so that you can develop your code on your windows and debug on linux. When you compile your executable file on Debian, you should be able to find the header file.

Comment: Unless you really want to make a cross-platform version, just use WSL and compile for Ubuntu first, where the headers should be largely identical.